# iOS hide default keyboard and open custom keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, uikeyboard

I have an `UITextview`, when user taps on `UITextview` i need to hide the default keyboard. For that i have done,

```
 [myTextView setEditable: NO];
```

So the keyboard is not shown, here i have created an Custom View with `UIButton`, i need to show this `UIView` when the user taps on `UITextView`, for that i have done,

```
textViewDidBeginEditing{

//Here i have added UIView as subview 

}
```

But this method is not working because of,

```
[myTextView setEditable: NO];
```

and i need to close the `UIView` when user clicks the close button inside the `UIView`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `resignFirstResponder` instead of setting the UITextView to not editable. This will hide the system keyboard.

```
 [myTextView resignFirstResponder];
```

If you want to use a different view for the keyboard then the system provided one then set `inputView` on the UITextView to the custom view you want to be used in place of the system keyboard.

```
myTextView.inputView = myCustomView;
```

Comment: what is the possible way to show my customview when user taps on UItTextVeiw..?

Comment: @HarishSaran Just set `inputView` on the UITextView to point to your custom view before the user taps on the UITextView perhaps in a `viewDidLoad` method on the controller

Comment: @Powers: I have a close button in my custom view how can i close the view when user taps the button, is removefromsuperview is the mothod to do that?

Comment: @HarishSaran If you are looking to close the keyboard with your custom view then you want to use `resignFirstRepsonder` on the UITextView to do that.

Comment: @Powers : Instead of default keyboard, i'm using the customview, which consists of one Button, when user taps on that button i want to close the mycustomview, Do resignFirstRepsonder do that?

Comment: @Powers : Can i change the customview POSITION and SIZE?

Comment: @HarishSaran I'm not sure, I've never tried changing the size. setup the inputView to the size you want it to be and try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` instead of `setEditable: NO` works?

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   //Here i have added UIView as subview 
   return NO;
}
```