# Titanium: Disable keyboard to use a custom numberpad

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am trying to use a custom number pad with a textfield to take advantage of blur and focus. But, how to disable the keyboard permanently on ios. Everything I tried does not work.

```
"Textfield": {
keyboardVisible: false
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use Keyboard Toolbar?

Comment: I can't style it the way I want it. I best workout around I found so far, although not perfect because it flashed a bit of a keyboard at times,  is to call 
    
    textfield.focus()
    textfield.blur()

Comment: How do you call your custom keyboard?

Comment: <pre>var timer = Alloy.createWidget('numpad_2', {
 callback : refreshData,
 callback1 : deleteMe,
 callback2 : clearme,
 callback3 : start
}).getView();

function doOpen(e) {

 timer.open();
}<pre>

Answer (score 2):

Well, i don't think there is a way to disable keyboard on textfield, but if you can call your custom keyboard on a `onClick` event, maybe you can use a label instead of textfield and open your keyboard on click.

I know that isn't a optimal solution but maybe it is useful.

Another way to solve this problem is open directly a default pad number with attribute `keyboardType : Ti.UI.KEYBOARD_DECIMAL_PAD` and use Keyboard Toolbar.

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible in Titanium, but it seems achievable on iOS:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16467767/4626813

You might want to do a Feature Request [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). Check if it has already been requested before you create a new ticket. Refer to this question and also link back to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.