# Disable iOS keyboard from displaying

Tags: swift

I'm doing an iPad app. I'm developing a custom keyboard. However, when I click on the textfield the default keyboard pops up. I want to prevent that disabling the keyboard.

I saw some similar posts here where they put a dummy View on top, or they disable the editing, but that won't do what I want.

[image]

Comment: Irrelevant to the question, but I don't think you can type a valid email using the keyboard shown.

Comment: That's a mockup. The real one has a @ on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you solve your problem.

[iOS hide default keyboard and open custom keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467422/ios-hide-default-keyboard-and-open-custom-keyboard)

Essentially you need to hide the default keyboard and then present your custom keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Using this you can disable normal keyboard

```
textField.inputView = UIView()
```

so putting your custom view can make the work

```
textField.inputView = YourKeyboard()
```

**EDIT 2**

Try to put this

```
youtTextField.inputAssistantItem.leadingBarButtonGroups.removeAll()
yourTextField.inputAssistantItem.trailingBarButtonGroups.removeAll()
```

Comment: It is crashing when I put that. This is what I get: 2018-11-26 12:23:19.922720-0500 Cleaner Pay[4067:403821] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'child view controller:<UICompatibilityInputViewController: 0x7f9efd50a5f0> should have parent view controller:<Cleaner_Pay.LoginVC: 0x7f9efd4083f0> but requested parent is:<UIInputWindowController: 0x7f9efd898e00>'. Any idea? I'll post the code here in a few.

Comment: Code too long to paste it here. But is not working. I tested it in an iPhone app and it works. But for some reason, in the iPad app, it puts the keyboard smaller below and not clickable.